# How to Stop form to be post if input is invalid in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

**About:** I want input field to be red if the user has inputted something wrong. and want to stop that field be posted as well.

**HTML Concept:** For this I have assigned data-input-validation to input which I want to validate.

**Js Concept:** Now in js I have created an object having two methods attached to it.
 1.**VALIDATION** *method* which takes 3 parameters (a. Type of validation which I want b. data-attribute of that field 3. Any input value otherwise (key up) on inputs will get value).
and after getting value this method pass those value to another method named **VALIDATING**.
2.**VALIDATING** *method* take 2 arguments passed by **VALIDATION** *method* (a. Defines type of validation we need b.value of input field to be validated).and applies these arguments to switch statement and in each case of switch statement I have defined regExp for every type of validation. after matching given value with regExp this method return a boolean value to First method which makes current input field to red or default according to the boolean value.

***Problem:*** Now I want to know how can I get boolean value from first **METHOD** so that I can prevent form being posted.

```
var inputValidation = function () {
this.validation = function (param1,param2,param3) {
    var input = $(document).find('[data-input-validation = ' + param2 + ']');
    input.each(function () {
        $(this).on('keyup',function(){
            input.each(function () {
                var value = $(this).val() || param3;
                var validate = new inputValidation();
                var result = validate.validating(param1,value);
                if(result) {
                    $(this).css('border','1px solid rgba(44,44,44,1)');
                }
                else {
                    $(this).css('border','1px solid #EF5350');
                }
            });
        });
    });
};

this.validating = function(param1,param2) {
    switch (param1) {
        case 'phoneNumber':
            var mobileNumber = new RegExp('^[0-9\-\s()+]{3,20}$');
            return mobileNumber.test(param2);
            break;
        case 'email':
            var email = new RegExp(/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/);
            return email.test(param2);
            break;
        case 'username':
            var username = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/);
            return username.test(param2);
            break;
        case 'message':
            var message = new RegExp(/(\/\w+) (\w+) (.+)/);
            return message.test(param2);
            break;
        }
    };
};

var validate = new inputValidation();
validate.validation('phoneNumber','search');
```

Comment: You can do it a bit different. Just set change event for your inputs and while the input will not match the regex pattern set its property/or class to invalid (or anything you like) so you can check if none of these inputs have invaild prop/class while pressing submit button eg:  `<input type="number" id="phoneNumber" invalid/>` or `<input type="number" id="phoneNumber" class="incorrect"/>`  return false

Comment: I was already thinking something like that. but  I want something more robust like what if I can create another get method which can hold the return value of validation method .and after that I can use that return value simply by calling when the form submit button is clicked. but I appreciate your answer its also perfect

Comment: I don't know the background and where are you going with this project, but according to my opinion it's unnecessarily complicated if you are just want to check if inputs content matches pattern while pressing submit button.

Comment: well truth is that in last i am using your solution as my answer :p thanks buddy for simple solution peace and love.